# PDOstatement::execute() expect parameter 1 to be array, string given in

Tags: php

Please help me to correct this code.
error at line

```
$stmt->execute($params = [], $query);
```

and when i open the file with dreamweaver every "$params=[]" is error.

-Databasse.php-

```
<?php 

include_once('connection.php'); //my connection is here

class Database extends connection{


public function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();
}

public function getRow($params = [], $query){
    try {
        $stmt = $this->datab->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute($params);
        return $stmt->fetch();  
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage());  
    }

}

public function getRows($query, $params = []){
    try {
        $stmt = $this->datab->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute($params);
        return $stmt->fetchAll();   
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage());  
    }
}
```

this is half of the source code database.php

Comment: Try `$params = array()` instead? Declaring an array with `[]` is not supported in older versions of PHP.

Comment: what error you are getting and what query/param you are passing in? please add some more details

Comment: Your error line is not in your code. You don't want to assign a variable when you call the function. And Dreamweaver may not be set to the correct version of PHP. What error do you get when you try to execute the code?

Comment: @PeregrineStudios i use php 5.5.38 . o have tried your suggestion, but still failed

Comment: @aynber 
actually, the code is not made by me. I downloaded it from sourcecodester. with keyword boat reservation free source code, i download it for my research, I got an assignment from school to investigate errors contained in a source code, and must fix the error

Comment: Is the error only from DW? Can you execute the code without problem?

Comment: @GabrielHeming no, the problem is i cant log in, and it say

Comment: @GabrielHeming Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp2\htdocs\boat\database\Database.php on line 21

Comment: hey guys you can download the source code at sourcecodester with keyword boat reservation free source code

Comment: From where you are calling getRow() method and what are you passing to this method as parameter. This getRow() method expect two parameter first one should be the array containing the table column name and corresponding value. The scond parameter must be the string (SQL statement). Make sure that you are passing `$myResult = getRow($array,$sql)`

Comment: Looking at your code, it's probably @ShaileshSingh is right. Check if the parameters are being send in correct order.

Comment: Add the type hint and your code will output if the parameters are in wrong order `getRow(array $params = [], $query` and `getRows($query, array $params = []){`. Last tip, never, never and never create two methods with almost same purpose with different parameters order.

Comment: @GabrielHeming Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Database::getRow() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\xampp2\htdocs\boat\login.php on line 13 and defined in C:\xampp2\htdocs\boat\database\Database.php:18 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp2\htdocs\boat\login.php(13): Database->getRow('SELECT * FROM t...', 'nurul123', '123456') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp2\htdocs\boat\database\Database.php on line 18

Comment: That's is your problem, the order of parameters is wrong. But here you put the array as first parameter, didn't you?

Comment: There's no array in this code `Database->getRow('SELECT * FROM t...', 'nurul123', '123456')`

Comment: @GabrielHeming login.php line 12 `$query = 'SELECT * FROM tourist WHERE tour_un = ? AND tour_up = ?';` line 13 `$result = $db->getRow($query, $un, $up);`

Comment: As I can see, the correct should be `$result = $db->getRow($query, [$un, $up]);`

Comment: @GabrielHeming thanks a lot, very very thanks. its work

Answer (score 2):

Need to see more of the code - what is your query string, what array w/ what values are you trying to feed into it?

Typically your query will have question marks `?` or might have keywords with colons `:mykeyword` as place holders for values, and then your array holds the values that are "prepared" and executed.

```
$query="select name from users where name=? and passwordHash=?";
$res=$connection->prepare($query);
$res->execute(array(
    "myuser",
    "dd02c7c2232759874e1c205587017bed"),
    );

// OR

$query="select name from users where name=:name and passwordHash=:passwordHash";
$res=$connection->prepare($query);
$res->execute(array(
    ":name" => "myuser",
    ":passwordHash" => "dd02c7c2232759874e1c205587017bed"),
    );
```

This does the query preparation, escaping, etc. and the "myuser" value replaces the first question mark and the hash string replaces the second.